# Insure and Go vs. Virgin travel insurance

Tags: insurance

I am looking for a travel insurance (I am resident of the UK). I looked at both Virgin Money travel insurance and InsureAndGo insurance - and it seems that the Virgin one is actually underwritten by InsureAndGo. Does anyone know if these two are exactly the same insurance, or are there any relevant differences?

Comment: Not sure about the UK.  The basic thing in the US is that the insurance companies will simply let the other companies resell their rebranded products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, Insure & Go is the [underwriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwriting#Insurance_underwriting) for both Insure & Go's products as well as Virgin Travel Insurance. Virgin Money does its own branding, pricing (similar products by the two companies have different prices - Virgin's seems higher), and customer support / claims (Virgin handles that for its own products). If you don't want to read a dense policy wording document, have a look at the 'keyfacts' document all insurance providers in the UK are supposed to publish to compare for [Virgin Money](https://travel.virginmoney.com/PolicyWording.aspx) and [Insure & Go](http://www.insureandgo.com/travel-insurance/policy-wording.html).